# Handling MouseUp on Slider in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, slider, mouseup

I've been working on incorporating a slider into a page in an app I'm working on.  My first attempt was to use the following in my template:

```
<span class="value">{{scaledDistThreshold}}%</span>
{{input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value=scaledDistThreshold}}
<button class="set" {{action "setDistThreshold"}}>Set</button>
```

This works; that is, I can use the slider and see the bound value change, and pressing the button will persist whatever value to the server.

What I'd like to do now is to *remove* the 'Set' button and persist on *mouseup* from the slider itself, and I'd prefer to do it with Ember as opposed to, say, a direct jQuery hook.  So far, my searches for sliders using Ember has turned up basically nothing.

Any ideas how I might accomplish this?  Thanks in advance!

---

**FOLLOW-UP EDIT**

Per Justin's answer, I was able to do the following:

```
App.InputRangeComponent = Em.TextField.extend({
  type: 'range',

  action: 'mouseUp',

  mouseUp: function () {
    var value = this.get('value');
    this.sendAction('action', value);
  }
});
```

I was then able to use this component in my markup as follows:

```
{{input-range min="0" max="100" step="1" value=scaledDistThreshold action="setDistThreshold"}}
```

The action I named gets called on mouse-up and passes along the current value of the slider, all as intended.  Thanks again to Justin for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My first thought, and this isn't, strictly-speaking, an answer to your question, but another option might be just saving the bound value on change, and throttling it to only do so, say, once every quarter-second or so.*

Now, as for answering your actual question:

(Please note: I'm still fairly new to Ember, so if what I say doesn't make sense, it's probably me, not you)

I didn't know that type="range" was an option for the {{input}} helper. Learn something new every day. :)

Take a look at the [Ember docs on the {{input}} helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_input). When you use type="text", Ember is creating an instance of Ember.TextField. You have a couple of options:

1. You can reopen Ember.TextField and add a mouseup event to it.
2. You can create your own, new helper, that uses a new view (that you create) that extends Ember.TextField.

I'd recommend #2 for fairly obvious reasons (you probably don't want every textfield you make doing the same thing on mouseup).

SO, option 2.

I *think* this is how it would go down. If not, hopefully, it will at least point you in the right direction, or someone will correct me.

First, you'll want to create a new view that extends Ember.TextEdit. Let's call it "rangeSlider".

```
var rangeSlider = Ember.TextField.extend({

});
```

Here is where you should add your mouseup event:

```
App.RangeSlider = Ember.TextField.extend({
    mouseUp: function(){
        //Do stuff here
    } 
});
```

Now, if you don't want to use {{view "App.RangeSlider"}}, you can create a new helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('rangeSlider', App.RangeSlider);
```

Then you just have to use {{rangeSlider}} to insert that view.

I'm not 100% sure how adding attributes via your new helper works, though.

Looking at the ember.js code, the {{input}} helper had a bit more going for it at declaration:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('input', function(options) {
  Ember.assert('You can only pass attributes to the `input` helper, not arguments', arguments.length < 2);

  var hash = options.hash,
      types = options.hashTypes,
      inputType = hash.type,
      onEvent = hash.on;

  delete hash.type;
  delete hash.on;

  if (inputType === 'checkbox') {
    Ember.assert("{{input type='checkbox'}} does not support setting `value=someBooleanValue`; you must use `checked=someBooleanValue` instead.", options.hashTypes.value !== 'ID');
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Ember.Checkbox, options);
  } else {
    if (inputType) { hash.type = inputType; }
    hash.onEvent = onEvent || 'enter';
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Ember.TextField, options);
  }
});
```

Now that I think about it, I wonder if there's a way to just extend an existing helper... Not sure. I'm not seeing anything in the API.

Anyway, hopefully, this will point you in the right direction. There may be a totally easier way, but this was the first thing that popped into my head when I read your question. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Justin.  I think you may be right about using a custom View...I was hoping to be able to leverage things that Ember already had (finding out about `type="range"` was a happy accident for me too) but I may have exceeded that scope here.

Comment: @brad_julian: if you haven't already, try popping into the #emberjs IRC channel on irc.freenode.net. Like here, it's kind of hit or miss whether someone will reply, but there are some pretty knowledgeable people in there from time to time. :)